# Sharepoint Document Renaming

Tags: sharepoint, document, renaming

How to rename a document in the document library using sharepoint object model coding.

Please help.

Thank you,

Rajshekar

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the properties on the SPFile.Item (title etc).

Comment: I believe we have to use event handlers. Do you have the code for the same.